# How to connect to machine using internet

Tags: remote-access

Can someone help me with options on how to connect and work on machines connected via the internet. This would require the ability to operate machines on Linux, Windows and Mac.

I heard about ssh tunneling. Any suggestions on how to implement this method or any other would be appreciated.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams I checked about ssh tunneling and trying to play around command line ... it seems too much involved so would liev to see if there are other options and then try with them

Comment: If you aren't comfortable with command line input the below answers will be more suited. SSH is entirely command line based. The Shell part in Secure Shell (SSH).

Comment: Thanks @MatthewWilliams yup below options seams promising experimenting with it ... i think it will work for mw

Answer (score 2):

Personally I use both Hamachi and TeamViewer. I use TeamViewer for RDP Access to my home machines. It's quick and easy to do. I use Hamachi to create a zero-config VPN into my home network without having to open up ports on the Firewall. This is handy because I can tunnel traffic through the VPN to one of my linux boxes and route all of my traffic through my home network (handy if the network my Remote is on blocks certain websites). I also use Hamachi to transfer files back and forth between my Remote & Home computers.

### TeamViewer

www.teamviewer.com

Supports remote control of a computer within or outside the network of the Host computer. Does not require opening ports on the firewall (router) of either location. Each computer with TeamViewer installed initiates a connection to the TeamViewer servers (3rd Party from your perspective) which will allow a direct link between Host and Guest. Supports File Transfers and is free for non-commercial use.

### Hamachi

www.logmein.com

Allow users to create a virtual private network with computers within or outside of the network of the Host computer. Does not require opening ports on the firewall (router) of either location. Each computer with Hamachi installed initiates a connection to the Hamachi servers (3rd Party from your perspective) which will allow a direct link between Host and Guest. Using your existing solution for initiating a remote connection into the Remote computer form the host will work as normal (Using the Hamachi IP Address of the Remote Computer)

### Port Forwarding

Dangerous and vulnerable. Only do this if you know how to secure the connection. This can open your network for attack and potential threats.

Comment: You use TeamViewer for RDP?  Weird.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any remote desktop application to do this. I personally have used  [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx), but there are plenty out there which can do this job for you.

> Remote control any computer or Mac over the internet within seconds or use Teamviewer for online meetings.

This is the simplest method and works on Windows, Linux and Mac.

Comment: Personally, I use a combination of TeamViewer and Hamachi. I use TeamViewer for remote RDP access into some home computers. I use Hamachi for a zero-config VPN to access files from servers.

Comment: @kobaltz | I agree, this VPN option is a good method. I only suggested Teamviewer alone as there was no mention of such security on the connection or file transfer requirements. +1 for the mention though.